# D3 how to pass Promise.all data further?

Tags: d3.js, charts

Could u have a look? no map appeared

https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/BaZYewv

```
async function chart()  {
  const [data,geo]  = await Promise.all([
    d3.json(promises[0]),
    d3.json(promises[1])
  ])
  console.log("data",data)
  console.log("geo", geo)
}
chart()

let path = d3.geoPath()

function ready(error,data,geo){
  //topojson object
  let topoobject = topojson.feature(geo, geo.objects.counties);
  let counties  = topoobject.features;
```

Comment: topoojson corrected.still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the data to the `ready` function. Right now in your code, the `ready` function is never called. You can do it like this:

```
Promise.all([
  d3.json(EDUCATION),
  d3.json(COUNTIES),
]).then(([data, geo]) => {
  ready(null, data, geo);
});
```

Also, there is a mistake in the `EDUCATION` url. It should be:

```
const EDUCATION = "https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/for_user_education.json";
const COUNTIES = "https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/counties.json";
```

Lastly, the first line of `ready` misspells `topojson`.